# Sending jsonstring as body with cUrl in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am having some issues with cUrl and jsonstring.

I have a PHP script which receives a jsonstring that looks like this:

```
'{"CreateDateTime":"20220405T000000","ExternalID":"","HCP":"36000","PHCP":"3","Course":{"ExternalID":"7A263511-A3EB-453A-BEE9-F36ED812E51D","ClubID":"1B39F017-FC26-405C-BEC0-67AA40C9360F","Name":"Marion Golfclub","Country":"US","TeeID":"","TeeName":"Yellow","TeePar":"72","TeeRating":"712000","TeeSlope":"129"}}'
```

Now, when trying to run a cUrl like this:

```
$url = "https://my.api.io/some@mail.com/clubs/members/exchangedscorecards";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: basic ahuYty5yTyuytgFLb1JBVEVycG9Daw=="
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"CreateDateTime":"20220405T000000","ExternalID":"","HCP":"36000","PHCP":"3","Course":{"ExternalID":"7A263511-A3EB-453A-BEE9-F36ED812E51D","ClubID":"1B39F017-FC26-405C-BEC0-67AA40C9360F","Name":"Marion Golfclub","Country":"US","TeeID":"","TeeName":"Yellow","TeePar":"72","TeeRating":"712000","TeeSlope":"129"}}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.ScorecardExchangeInput]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'CreateDateTime', line 1, position 18.
```

What am I doing wring, or what am I missing?

Really hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: So how exactly does this error relate to your cURL request itself? The message rather sounds like the receiver did not like the way your JSON was structured ...?

Comment: Reading the error message, the receiving script requires not just a JSON Object, but more specific a List of the type `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[Entities.ScorecardExchangeInput]`. The data you post is a valid serialized JSON object, but not the format expected.